# How to fill polygons with even-odd rule?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, directx, game-engine

I have n polygons. Each Polygon has n points, and some other properties like bounding box and etc. I can fill them separetly in some color , but i want to fill polygons with even-odd rule. [image: like this]Which algorithms are there for this ? (may be vector based or raster based)

Comment: Maybe program it yourself? If `SomePixel` belongs to `odd number` of polygons or `even number`

Comment: The answer is basically the same as the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422846/how-to-force-opengl-to-draw-a-non-convex-filled-polygon. Even though that one was for a single polygon, but the same solution works for multiple polygons.

Answer (score 1):

If raster is OK for you, calculate all cross points of edges vs line (list of intersections per line). Put horizontal lines between raster lines, so [for square] line above has no edge intersections, line under has two intersections.

Now go for every line from left to right per intersection, you start "outside", and every intersection you invert the current state.

*(BTW, you may assert that you end "outside" as well ... of course I'm talking about infinite x-res, you may further constrain it to some fixed resolution, but calculation starts where ever is the first intersection, and I would run till the last one, just for that assert check)*

It may be tricky to get the almost-horizontal lines correctly, and connection between two edges (imagine sharp end of star, going down and up at the same raster pixel, with only 0.1px x-coord diff, etc.).

I would probably draw some pictures on paper, if clean math will do, or some corner-case logic is needed, then unit test heavily.

---

If you want full vector, it's basically the same, just it's not per line, but per each end of edge y-coord (creating virtual line) to calculate all intersections with other edges.

Actually this may be tad easier to write, but then it may be tad more difficult to apply the result on raster image. IMHO (far from feeling "sure", been long time since I did this).

Answer (score 1):

Using stencil flipping should be the most efficient raster-based method to do this. Do one pass to populate the stencil buffer ( e.g. `glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP,GL_INVERT)`) and a second pass with a full-screen quad that sets the color depending on the stencil buffer's values (e.g. `glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1 ,1)`)